# FFMPEG: Timing wrong in output

Tags: ffmpeg

one question that currently drives me crazy. I used the following command to cut a video:

```
ffmpeg -i origin.mp4 -ss 00:09:53 -to 00:11:53 -async 1 output.mp4
```

However, the output does not start at 09 minutes and 53 seconds, but **at 10:38** of the original mp4. The length (2 minutes) is correct in the output... I don't get the problem.
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: that's very strange. Have you tried this on a different file? Maybe the mp4 is corrupted and thus displays a wrong timecode... or could it be that there is a timecode already embedded, starting at 2:00 ?

Comment: Share the input if you can.

Comment: I checked the input file and it has a strange behaviour: It starts at 00:00 and after two seconds it jumps to 00:23. And, if I open it with a different media player, it skips the first 40 seconds... strange. Can I repair that with ffmpeg?

Comment: Ok, I got it - the input file war indeed broken! Thanks!